# Complex annotation to get all statuses for each user counted

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

In my leads table I need to count the number of leads for each status for each user. Is there any way to do that by arm annotate? Right now I have something like this:

```
leads.objects.values("created_by","status").annotate(total=Count("status")).order_by("created_by")
```

and output is like:

```
[{'created_by':"Andrew Ray', "status":'ACTIVE", 'total':4}, {'created_by':Andrew Ray', "status":'LOST", 'total':2}, {'created_by':Andrew Ray', "status":'WON", 'total':1}]
```

is there a way to get it like this:

```
[{'created_by':"Andrew Ray', "ACTIVE" : 4, "LOST": 2, "WON":1}]
```

*Active*, *Won*, and *Lost* are values of STATUS field in leads model. There is also another there and I would like to make key and value pair for each of them for each user (CharField)

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: I'm not able to share the whole cause I'm not allowed to but it looks like that status field is from enum : Status =[ (Leadstatus.ACTIVE.value, "Active"),(Leadstatus.WON.value, "Won")] and few more statuses

Comment: Is `created_by` a foreign key? Just that part of the model would help

Comment: Yes it's foreign key I'm using created_by__name to get the name of it sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your model, something like the following should work.

Create a values queryset on the unique field (`created_by`) and order by that field. Then you annotate the queryset with counts that are filtered by the status you want to count per the unique field. We can construct the annotations dynamically by using the values from the choices enum, creating and then unpacking a dict with all the choices to pass the counts as keywords

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Leads.objects.order_by(
    'created_by'
).values(
    'created_by'
).annotate(
    total=Count('pk'),
    **{choice: Count('pk', filter=Q(status=choice)) for choice in Leads.StatusEnum.values}
)
```

Comment: Thank You for Your help but I'm trying to find a way to not hardcode status values if it's possible

Comment: @KarolSawicki okay, does the status field have choices that can be used to generate the fields or do you have to get then from the database?

Comment: yes it's choices field from enum

Comment: @KarolSawicki Updated the answer with a way of dynamically creating the annotations using the enum

Comment: @KarolSawicki if this answers your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer, it can help others that have the same issue